# Windows Phone crop view

Tags: c#, image, windows-phone-8, telerik, crop

Many apps provide this "crop" view with the white rectangle. How can I get this view?
I just want to force a user to pick a predifined size. I also have the telerik controls, if their Imageeditor helps forcing a size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best way to do it is to set

```
PixelHeight
PixelWidth
```

on the chooser to the preferred size.